# Issue with composer: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I run composer update I get an error message:

> "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages".

I uploaded some screenshots of the issue below:

[image: Error message 1]
[image: Error message 2]

This is what my composer.json file looks like.

Composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
   "framework",
   "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
   "php": "^7.2.5",
   "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
   "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
   "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
   "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
   "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
   "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
   "intervention/image": "2.*",
   "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1"
},
"require-dev": {
   "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
   "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
   "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
   "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
   "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
   "optimize-autoloader": true,
   "preferred-install": "dist",
   "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
   "laravel": {
       "dont-discover": []
   }
},
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "App\\": "app/"
   },
   "classmap": [
       "database/seeds",
       "database/factories"
   ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
   "psr-4": {
       "Tests\\": "tests/"
   }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
   "post-autoload-dump": [
       "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
       "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
   ],
   "post-root-package-install": [
       "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
   ],
   "post-create-project-cmd": [
       "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
   ]
}
}
```

Comment: Error messages that are pure text can be shared best as text

Comment: Ivan, do you have any more questions about this topic?

Answer (score -1):

As the error message already tells you: you try to mix different versions of Laravel. `laravelcollective/html` with the version requirement `^6.1` requires Laravel v6 or v7, and some lines above you require Laravel 5.2. Either upgrade `laravel/framework` to a later version, or downgrade `laravelcollective/html` to a version that is compatible